# cannot get mouse coordinates on wheel events

Tags: javascript, coordinates, mousewheel

Hello problem is on mozilla firefox browser mouse wheel event doesn't have parameters who can get mouse position coordinates i use jquery 1.9.0 version wheel events:

```
$("#element").bind("mousewheel wheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll MouseWheelEvent", function (transsmittedEvent) {
var evt = window.event || transsmittedEvent;

if (evt.clientX !== undefined && evt.clientY !== undefined) {
        var x = evt.clientX;
        var y = evt.clientY;
    };
} else if(evt.pageX !== undefined && evt.pageY !== undefined) {
        var x = evt.pageX;
        var y = evt.pageY;
    };        
} else if(evt.offsetX !== undefined && evt.offsetY !== undefined) {
        var x = evt.offsetX;
        var y = evt.offsetY;
}     
});
```

trasmittedEvent doesn't have parameters who can get coordinates: pageX, offsetX, clientX and etc. but window.event have all this in chrome, but in mozilla firefox window.event is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the built-in browser event by looking at [`transsmittedEvent.originalEvent`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

This has `clientX` and `pageX` in Firefox as well as Chrome.